# extern "C" linkage inside C++ namespace?

Tags: c++, c, namespaces

```
namespace someNameSpace {
    extern "C" void doSomething()
        {
             someOperations();
        }
}
```

I want to run `doSomething()` in both C++ and C environment.

Is `someNameSpace` still encapsulating `doSomething()` if I expose it to `extern "C"` linkage?

Is there a good way to share functions between C++ and C while avoiding polluting global namespace on C++ side?

**Edit**: Because this code is primarily used in C++ mode, while the C linkage is for test use only, I guess this is a better way to do it.

```
namespace someNameSpace {
    #ifdef COMPILE_FOR_C_LINKAGE
    extern "C"
    #else
    extern "C++"
    #endif
    { 
        void doSomething()
            {
                 someOperations();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use it in a C program? If so, what happened?

Comment: @RyanJ Yes, I tried, it compiles and links well in both C++ and C. I haven't run it yet.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your code works, but you should beware that all functions that have `extern "C"` linkage share the same space of names, but that is not to be confused with the C++ notion of "namespace": Your function is really `someNameSpace::doSomething`, but you cannot have any other `extern "C"` function with unqualified name `doSomething` in any other namespace.

See 7.5/6:

> At most one function with a particular name can have C language linkage. Two declarations for a function
>   with C language linkage with the same function name (ignoring the namespace names that qualify it) that
>   appear in different namespace scopes refer to the same function. Two declarations for a variable with C
>   language linkage with the same name (ignoring the namespace names that qualify it) that appear in different
>   namespace scopes refer to the same variable. An entity with C language linkage shall not be declared with
>   the same name as a variable in global scope, unless both declarations denote the same entity; no diagnostic is
>   required if the declarations appear in different translation units. A variable with C language linkage shall not
>   be declared with the same name as a function with C language linkage (ignoring the namespace names that
>   qualify the respective names); no diagnostic is required if the declarations appear in different translation
>   units. [*Note*: Only one definition for an entity with a given name with C language linkage may appear in
>   the program (see 3.2); this implies that such an entity must not be defined in more than one namespace
>   scope. — *end note*]

Your company's or project's global style arbiters should be able to advise you on a suitable naming policy for your code base.

Comment: An entity with C language linkage shall not be declared with the same name as a variable in global scope, unless both declarations denote the same entity;    ---- Is this a "entity vs variable" statement? I experimented with g++ 4.3.3 and it seems true. Conflict occurs only when I re-declare an global variable like "extern int doSomething=1;" but it's OK if I define another "extern void doSomething(){}" as long as it's not another extern C linkage.

Answer (score 22):

Just piece of code to illustrate behavior stated in Kerrek SB answer

```
#include <iostream>

namespace C{
    void Hello(){
        std::cout<<"Hello"<<std::endl;
    }
    extern "C" void HelloThere(){
        std::cout<<"Hello There from extern \"C\""<<std::endl;
    }
}

extern "C" void HelloThere();

int main() {
    C::Hello();
    C::HelloThere(); //Compiles
    //Hello(); <--- does not compile
    HelloThere(); //Also compiles and prints the same as C::HelloThere() !!!

    return 0;
}
```

Live at http://ideone.com/X26wfR

Answer (score 5):

In C++ ABI, namespaces have to be mangled. So this:

```
namespace foo
{
    void bar(int){}
}
```

is translated more or less to such symbol:

```
foo::bar(int)
```

When you force the compiler to use C ABI, the similar symbol

```
namespace foo
{
    extern "C" void bazz(int){}
}
```

after compilation looks like following:

```
bazz
```

You can see the difference in the godbolt:
https://godbolt.org/z/BmVpSQ

In C ABI there are no namespaces or argument list mangled with the function, so you can only have 1 such symbol in the whole code. Defining it twice:

```
namespace foo
{
    extern "C" void bazz(int){}
}

namespace foo2
{
    extern "C" void bazz(int){}
}

int main()
{
    foo2::bazz(5);
    return 0;
}
```

...is illegal. The clang compiler just emits simple compilation error in such case:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/r5CUXm7OKePtG35L

The gcc compiler emits error too, but it looks way more misterious:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/BiN0auna9klBg5GE

Comment: Not sure if it was different at the time this answer was posted, but gcc seems to be emitting an error during compilation when I clicked the link (interestingly, at the assembly stage, which is I think the first time I've ever seen an error in that stage of compilation)

Comment: @DominickPastore you are right - edited the error message is very strange though. I've edited the answer.