# Importing C enum into C++ namespace

Tags: c++, c, enums

I am writing a C++ wrapper for a C library. In the C library, I have a

```
typedef enum {bar1,bar2} Foo; /* this is defined in the C library */
```

that I'd like to "bring" into a C++ namespace. I am using

```
namespace X{
    using ::Foo;
}
```

to achieve this. However, to qualify the enum members, I always have to refer to them as

```
X::Foo::bar1
```

and so on. Is there any way whatsoever of "importing" the C enum into a C++ namespace but refer directly to the values of the enum as

```
X::bar1
```

and so on? Or, in other words, can I import directly the values of the enum into the namespace?

**EDIT**

I do not think the question is a dupe, please see my answer as I realized there is a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using declaration with enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438192/using-declaration-with-enum)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just how *using declaration* works. Global `Foo` and `bar1` are two different names. Your *using declaration* brings name `Foo` into namespace `X`, but does not bring any other names from global namespace (like names of the enum members). For that you'd need

```
namespace X {
  using ::Foo;
  using ::Foo::bar1;
  using ::Foo::bar2;
}
```

Comment: I realized I can also do `namespace X{ extern "C" {include <C_library>} }` which will do it for me. For some reason I though I cannot have C linkage inside namespaces...

Answer (score 1):

A solution that works for me is to do

```
namespace X{
    extern "C"{
        #include <C_library.h>
    }
}
```

Before trying it I had the impression that I cannot put C-linkage functions inside a namespace, but it turns out I was wrong. Then I can simply do

```
X::bar1
```

to access the C enum member `bar1` from `typedef enum {bar1, bar2} Foo;`.

See e.g. [extern "C" linkage inside C++ namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28996944/3093378)