# Compose C header file to be able to be used from C++

Tags: c++, c, software-design, library-design

I'm working on some library header file that is supposed to be used from both C and C++. Since C does not have a namespace concept I would add a "library prefix" to all names defined in the header file. By contrast, for C++ I would define a namespace. So I currently think of the design as something like this:

`mylib.h`

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
namespace mylib{
#define NAME_PREFIX(identifier) identifier
extern "C" {
#else
#define NAME_PREFIX(identifier) mylib_identifier
#endif

int NAME_PREFIX(foo)(void);

//other declarations go here

#ifdef __cplusplus
} //extern "C"
} //namespace mylib
#endif
```

I have never seen something like that so I am not sure if that is common. Is it discouraged to do so? What are possible drawbacks?

Comment: How are you going to link object files from C and C++ based on this header if the names don't match?

Comment: I've never seen that before either, but I like it--assuming `extern c` still works inside a namespace, of course.

Comment: @Chipster [`extern "C"` does work inside namespaces.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996944/extern-c-linkage-inside-c-namespace)

Comment: @uneven_mark Agree, that's a problem in general. But is it in case of header-only libraries... ?

Comment: @St.Antario If there is no external linkage between languages for the library, you don't need `extern "C"`.

Comment: @uneven_mark So yes, it introduces much more problems than solves...

Comment: I think it is already a bad idea because the unprefixed `extern "C"` name will pollute the global (C) namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, as I mentioned in the comments, there are three problems I see with this approach.

First, it does not allow the library to be used with mixed C/C++ translation if any entities are supposed to share linkage between the two languages. If the header file is included in a C translation unit and a C++ translation unit, all declared entities will have different names, either with a prefix or without one. So in effect it will work out as if these were two separate libraries, one used in the C translation unit and one in the C++ translation unit. If any library entities are supposed to share linkage between the translation units, it won't work.

Second, `extern "C"` inside the namespace will scope the name properly inside the namespace for C++ code. However, in order to guarantee C linkage, the name without namespace prefix must be introduced into the global C namespace, cluttering it with lots of names without a library prefix.

Third, it makes it difficult to write user code that should be translatable between C and C++ as well. Any such user would have to introduce a similar macro.

If the library is not supposed to be used in mixed C/C++ code (or without any shared linkage), then `extern "C"` is unnecessary and after removing it, I think the approach may be fine.