# Can I include a headerfile in a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files, conio

I am using the `<conio.h>` header file, and somewhere else in my source code I define a function with the name `getch` and it has to have that name. Since there already is a `getch` in `<conio.h>`, and this header file declares all of its functions in the global namespace, I get a name collision.

I found that using the following syntax would avoid the collision:

```cpp
namespace some_namespace
{
    #include <conio.h>
}
```

Then I can use `some_namespace::getch` when I want to access the function in `<conio.h>` and `getch` when I want to access my own function.

Is this valid syntax? I know `<conio.h>` is only for windows, but is this kind of syntax going to behave the same across all the compilers? What other ways do you suggest to get around this problem?

### Edit:

I use GCC and MSVC 2019 on Windows and it compiles fine on both of them.

I can access the functions in `<conio.h>` as well, `getch` in particular as I showed above (even though I should use the name `_getch` instead of `getch` in MSVC).

Comment: Why not put your own code (including your `getch`) in your own namespace?

Comment: Don't forget to `extern "C"` as well, `<conio.h>` is a C header file.

Comment: @S.M. I tried it with both gcc and MSVC 2019 and it works on both of them.

Comment: You should put your getch() in your namespace.

Comment: The standard headers were written with the intention that they be used in the global namespace. If this kind of hackery happens to work it's only by accident, and it could well fail with a different compiler (including a future version of the compiler you're using now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System header files like `<conio.h>` which are intended to be used in both C and C++ will enclose their declarations in an `extern C` scope, forcing C linkage for all that is contained in them, regardless of whatever additional C++ namespaces you add. That’s why your code compiles in this case.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996944/extern-c-linkage-inside-c-namespace), which is almost a duplicate of this question, but not exactly.

In short, yes it’s valid, but I would strongly encourage against it. There are many other ways to solve this problem, like creating wrapper modules for the functions you want to have alternate symbols for.

As a side note: try putting your own `getch` in an `extern C` block. My guess is you’ll get a linker error.